# Python: 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)' for a username password system

Tags: python, dictionary

I am getting this error 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)' when I am making a dictionary from a text file when there is more than 1 key and value in the text file.

```
database = {}  #creates an empty dictionary
with open("file.txt", "r") as infile:  #opens the dictionary
    for line in infile: #for each line
        name, ask = line.strip().split(':') 
        database[name] = (ask)


name = input('Enter username: ')
ask = input('Enter pin: ')
if name in database:
    if ask in database[name]:
        print('Welcome', name)

    else:
        database.update( {name : ask} )
        print(database)
else:
    database.update( {name : ask} )
    print(database)


with open('file.txt', 'w') as file: 
    file.write(json.dumps(database)) #updates the text file with the new databse
```

I expect when the program runs and there is more than 1 key and value in the text file to run no matter which key is input. However if there is more than 1 key/value in the file, the text file can't be unpacked

Comment: Can you provide an example line from "file.txt"?

Comment: Here's what the text file has in it as of right now which creates an error: {"name" : "hello", "man" : "mane"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a simple json file?

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as infile:
    database = json.loads(infile.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Check all the lines in your **file.txt** file. There might be a case where the occurrence of ":" is more than one. Since, you are unpacking the list into two variables. If there are more than two values in the resulting list on line 4, i.e. line.strip().split(":"), it will raise an exception.

Comment: the contents of the file is: {"name" : "hello", "man" : "mane"}

Comment: The content of file seems to be a JSON data. You can use json module's load() function to load the data as dictionary. Also, make sure that keys are unique in the file.

Comment: would it just be load(file.txt)

Comment: load() function requires a file object to read from. You can refer this document https://realpython.com/python-json/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Using pythons function `eval`, you can parse the string read from the file to a dictionary. Then you can write it to your dictionary

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as infile:  #opens the dictionary
    for line in infile: #for each line
        entry = eval(line)
        database[entry["name"]] = entry["man"]
```

Comment: With this: i tried inputting the key: 'name' for username and value: 'hello' for pin. This resulted in the output: {'hello': 'mane', 'name': 'hello'} and changed the contents of the text file to: {"hello": "mane", "name": "hello"}

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import ast

with open("file.txt", "r") as infile:  #opens the dictionary
    for line in infile: #for each line
        eval_dict = ast.literal_eval(line) # This gives you a dictionary
        database[name] = eval_dict["name"]
```

**Note:**

As per @jaggers comment,

I have consider `{"name" : "hello", "man" : "mane"}` line in text file.

Comment: this returns the error: NameError: name 'name' is not defined. This is for the line:    database[name] = eval_dict["name"]

Comment: @jaggers, you have mentioned an example of text line present in the file in question comments. I have used the same to create program. What is text in your text file?

Comment: the contents of the text file is: {"name" : "hello", "man" : "mane"}  however i need the code to work no matter what is in the text file as this can be subject to change as users may change their details, users may delete their account or new users may be added to the dictionary

Comment: @jaggers No matter the data is getting deleted or added. The property of dictionary is keys should be unique. values can be updated. If you have to maintain users dictionary, what I can suggest you is, create a `id's` as keys and maintain dictionary as value of that key.

Comment: That will be completely out of the scope of this question. `users_dict = {'1':{'name':'hello1', 'man':'mane1'}, '2':{'name':'hello2', 'man':'mane2'}`. You can consider this as something similar example as i said.

Answer (score 0):

Your code opens the file, then iterates over it line by line.
If it is exactly as you say in your comment to your original question, then the first *line* is:

```
 {"name" : "hello", "man" : "mane"}
```

That can't be parsed in your code.

If your file was instead of this form:

```
"name":"hello"
"man":"mane"
```

(the newline is implicit) then it would work fine.

The mistake appears to be that you are thinking that a text file that looks like a Python dictionary will be automagically parsed by Python as a dictionary: It won't, which is why you have got other answers here that suggest using eval() or similar to parse it for you.

You might want to consider using the json module to read and write dictionary-like files.

hth

Comment: oh i see what you mean. Would you know how to make the code create the text in the file in this format

Comment: also would the actual verification system still work with the code written in the original question?

Comment: There are always several ways to do things like this. My suggestion would be read the file in in the same format as you are writing it out and continue to use the json module to do so.  Presumably this is a learning exercise for you? In which case, I'll leave it to you to look up the documentation.